# Save Data into a file in spreedsheat form

Tags: java, android

So i was wondering if there is a way to save my data into a file ,such as a txt file or excel spreedsheatform?  (xml parsing?)  Because i want row for date, time ,size etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an excel file in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006087/how-to-create-an-excel-file-in-android)

Comment: Not compeltly , I saw the topic before but wasnt exactly what i wanted. The idea is to do it format it would including an external library that isnt part of android framework. I want to learn how to do it programicly:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your data in [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format and import the file to Excel whenever you need it in a spreadsheet format.