# Duplicated classes found in modules classes.jar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Working with **"[Cxense](https://github.com/cXense) SDK for Android"**, I'm getting the message of duplicated class:

```
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (**com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1**) and classes.jar (**com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0**)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0) 
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0) 
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ListFragment found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0) 
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0) 
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0) 
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0)
```

This is my app level **build.gradle** configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tototita.cxensetestapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' 
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

     //**CXsense
     implementation 'com.cxpublic:cxense-android:1.0.1'
}
```

How could I avoid this duplicated classes that are surely contained in Cxense SDK?

Comment: do you post all dependencies here, I just add in a sample project and I don't get any error

Comment: Do you have the same configuration ?   compileSdkVersion 27, targetSdkVersion 27 etc?

Comment: More info:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029393/why-im-getting-duplicate-class-when-running-my-android-project/56029604#56029604

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If there are duplicates, use `exclude`:

```
implementation ('com.cxpublic:cxense-android:1.0.1') {
    exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-v4"
}
```

Or remove `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'` in favour of `support-v4`.

See: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-exclude-specific-transitive-dependencies-of-something-i-depend-on/17991

Comment: @aucd29 i am using this :

implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.0.0'

Getting this error 

Duplicate class com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteActivity found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:2.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0)

Comment: can you please tell me in build.gradle where to put this line ?? in packagingoption or in dependencies ?

Answer (score 37):

There are two ways to fix your issue.

1. Excluding **duplicated dependencies** while `implementation` **individually**,
2. Excluding **duplicated dependencies** from every `implementation`s in **generic way**.

### Let's first understand the problem :

Here, in your case artifact **`com.android.support`** is duplicated, because your **app module** uses version : **27.1.1** while your artifact **`com.cxpublic:cxense-android:1.0.1`** is having internal dependency of **`com.android.support`** uses version : **22.2.0**.

So, you should remove one of them manually *(removing older or lower version is recommended)*. Let's try to remove it !

---

**By first approach:**

```
implementation ('com.cxpublic:cxense-android:1.0.1') {
    exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-v4"
}
```

Putting **exclude** for *group* **`com.android.support`** in our artifact `com.cxpublic:cxense-android:1.0.1` will not get imported for **`support-v4`** libraries when we use our implementation on this artifact.

So, issue would be resolved by manually putting this block to every artifact having this conflict.

**By Second way:**

We can remove **included dependencies** and replace them with one package with latest number. In our case, it is **`support-v4`** with different version. So, go to the android block of app level **build.gradle** and put below block there to remove duplicated **`support-v4`** from all artifacts, so that we can have distinct dependency.

```
android {
    // Some other stuffs
    configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'support-v4' // This removes all other versions of `support-v4` if gets duplicated from all the artifacts.
    }
    // Rest of other stuffs
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simple delete the caches folder from below path and rebuild the project. Then it builds everything afresh.

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.gradle
```