# Duplicate class a.a.a.a.a.a found in modules classes.jar (com.stripe:stripe-3ds2-android:4.0.5) and classes.jar (opentok-android-sdk-2.18.0.aar)

Tags: android, opentok

My application uses stripe sdk and opentok sdk, i just updated the two sdks for versions 15.1.0 and 2.18.0 respectively. Android studio is giving the above error when building the project. I cannot exclude any class because i dont know the functionality of each and where it used. The two classes are each found in obfscated packages. What can i do to fix this error without downgrading any of the sdks? Thanks.

These are two different classes with the same obfuscated name a.a.a.a.a.a

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicated classes found in modules classes.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56695106/duplicated-classes-found-in-modules-classes-jar)

Comment: No because these are two different classes in different packages from different sdks and I cannot exclude any classs because i dont know the functionality of each and where it used

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and was able to fix this by downgrading opentok sdk version from 2.18.0 to 2.16.0, synced the project and invalidating the cache and restart.

Comment: Hello Shehryar, yeah i am aware of that, i didnt want to downgrade opentok, i filed two tickets to stripe and opentok and both promised to fix the issue.

Comment: Good to know that. Please let me know here when the issue is fixed from stripe and opentok. Thanks

Comment: Opentok fixed the issue