# Duplicate class com.facebook.. found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, gradle, duplicates

[com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2] /Users/gagangupta/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0f1732d94a06d041909e2f52d4f8dad0/transformed/jetified-react-native-0.69.2-debug/AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Package name 'com.facebook.react' used in: com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2, com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3.

> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> ReactNativeFirebase WARNING: NPM package '@react-native-firebase/remote-config' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v17.3.0 but found v15.7.1, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
335 actionable tasks: 13 executed, 322 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.facebook.debug.debugoverlay.model.DebugOverlayTag found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.debug.holder.NoopPrinter found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.debug.holder.Printer found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.debug.holder.PrinterHolder found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.debug.tags.ReactDebugOverlayTags found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeAccessibilityInfoSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeAccessibilityManagerSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeActionSheetManagerSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeAlertManagerSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeAnimatedModuleSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeAnimatedTurboModuleSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeAnimationsDebugModuleSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeAppStateSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeAppearanceSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeBlobModuleSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeBugReportingSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeClipboardSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeDatePickerAndroidSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeDevLoadingViewSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeDevMenuSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeDevSettingsSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeDevSplitBundleLoaderSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeDeviceEventManagerSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeDeviceInfoSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeDialogManagerAndroidSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeExceptionsManagerSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeFileReaderModuleSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeFrameRateLoggerSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeHeadlessJsTaskSupportSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)
> Duplicate class com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeI18nManagerSpec found in modules jetified-react-android-0.71-debug.3-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.3) and jetified-react-native-0.69-debug.2-debug-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.69.2)

deleted gradle cache, tried cleaning and deleting node modules

Answer (score 1):

By reference [Duplicated classes found in modules classes.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56695106/duplicated-classes-found-in-modules-classes-jar), I figured out a solution:

In android/app/build.gradle, add following in your Android {} node

```
android {
...
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: "com.facebook.react", module: "react-native"
    }
}
```

The reason is that some dependency packages still using "react-native" instead of "react-android" in their build.gradle.

> implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'