# Duplicate class while upgrading to Gradle plugin to 3.4.2 from 2.3.3

Tags: android

I was upgrading Android Studio from 2.3.3 to 3.4.2. I could resolve grade sync issues but while executing the code I get following errors.
This is the first time I am upgrading my Android St

Error Received -

```
Cause 1: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$Delegate found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$DelegateProvider found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$SlideDrawable found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback21Impl found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.ActivityManagerCompat found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable.run(CheckDuplicateClassesDelegate.kt:132)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.externalInterruptibleAwaitDone(ForkJoinTask.java:361)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1001)
    ... 81 more
```

Here is the code in build.gradle (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is the code in build.gradle (Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "arve.tech.arvesmarthome"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 2
        versionName "3.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.github.anastr:speedviewlib:1.1.6'
    compile 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:1.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I'm Getting Duplicate Class When Running My Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029393/why-im-getting-duplicate-class-when-running-my-android-project)

Comment: This might be your solution check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029393/why-im-getting-duplicate-class-when-running-my-android-project