# Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.ListPreloader found in modules glide-4.3.1-runtime.jar

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using maps places services with the migration. here is my Gradle app

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta2'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'
```

Following error occurs while debugging

```
Duplicate class com.bumptech.glide.Priority found in modules glide-4.3.1-runtime.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1) and glide-4.3.1.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029393/why-im-getting-duplicate-class-when-running-my-android-project/56029604#56029604

Comment: By following the steps I get 'error: cannot access zzb
class file for com.google.firebase.iid.zzb not found'

Answer (score 2):

use this :-

```
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
```

instead of :-

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'
```

Comment: After changing this I get 'Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfb`.'