# Multiple "Duplicate Class" Errors in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I'm trying to run my Android App but I get following Errors:

```
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract found in modules annotations-13.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.21.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.21)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.Nls found in modules annotations-13.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.21.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.21)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.NonNls found in modules annotations-13.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.21.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.21)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull found in modules annotations-13.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.21.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.21)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable found in modules annotations-13.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.21.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.21)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.PropertyKey found in modules annotations-13.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.21.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.21)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.TestOnly found in modules annotations-13.0.jar (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0) and jetified-kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.21.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.3.21)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

I can't really wrap my head around these kinds of errors since I'm not even using Kotlin in any way in my entire app. It's configured as a Java app.

My build.gradle (Module: App) looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude "**/kotlin/**"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:2.0.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-integration:2.0.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.web3j/parity
    implementation 'org.web3j:core:4.5.7'
    implementation 'org.web3j:parity:4.5.5'
}
```

The other build.gradle (Project: App) looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I added `mavenCentral()` and `jcenter()` to the repositories after I read other questions/answers on StackOverflow from people with similar Duplicate Class Errors.

Comment: Try using exclude group: 'com.google.common', module: 'annotations'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56029393/6071729

Comment: Thank you guys but this still not resolves my problem.