# Duplicate class when library used in Android

Tags: android, gradle, worker, android-workmanager

I'm building a library for other developers to use in another projects, let's call it SDK.

My SDK uses the Android class `Worker` to schedule background jobs, and I'm using this library:

`androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0`

One of the developers that uses SDK had a problem of duplicate classes when implemented my SDK, because another library was importing the same classes of work-runtime. But not in the same package:

`android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1`

If I ask the developer to use `exclude` when implementing my SDK, then it will try to use the classes with a lower version (1.0.1), so it'll be in another version that I didn't tested. I already tried this.

What can I do to resolve this duplicate problem because both libraries have the same classes? It's possible to maintain both libraries with different versions in separate scopes?

This is the error:

```
  Duplicate class androidx.work.BackoffPolicy found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1) and classes.jar (androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.work.Configuration found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1) and classes.jar (androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.work.Configuration$Builder found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1) and classes.jar (androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.work.Constraints found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1) and classes.jar (androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.work.Constraints$Builder found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1) and classes.jar (androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.work.ContentUriTriggers found in modules classes.jar (android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1) and classes.jar (androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0)
  ...
```

Thank you!

Comment: How are they not in the same package? There are multiple ways around this, including releasing your SDK as an uber-jar with shaded dependencies. Yes, explicit excludes may or may not work.

Comment: The classes come from two different libraries android.arch and androidx.work.. I'll search for uber-jars with shaded dependencies to try to solve my problem, thank you

Comment: I created an example app using the SDK, and when I use the same library in both ends, with different versions, it works okay.. I think it's something to do with the classes coming from two different libraries.

Comment: When you use the full classified package, does the conflict still occur?

Comment: complete answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/56029604/6071729

Comment: @Mr.AF but this will not exclude the library from androidx.work on the app using my SDK? This will make my library use the older versions of Worker, right?

Comment: @LucasReis did you read it completely ? there are several kinds and solution for different issues .

Comment: @Mr.AF I'll try to make some of the solutions, thank you

Comment: @Mr.AF the solution with exclude and jetifier didn't work.. unfortunately

Comment: add all of the duplicated classes like this example to configuration section . all*.exclude group:'androidx.work.BackoffPolicy' module: 'classes.jar'

Comment: @Mr.AF I'll try that

Comment: @Mr.AF there is much more classes than described above, doing this will be too much, I configured what you ask for one of the classes and it did not work :/

Comment: add just this group:'androidx.work' module: 'classes.jarand check if it works

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work :/

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, did you find a solution?