# Duplicated class found using DropBox SDK

Tags: android, class, android-studio, dropbox

Using DropBox sdk 3.1.3 is giving me following errors:

```
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.AccessErrorException found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.ApiErrorResponse found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.ApiErrorResponse$Serializer found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.BadRequestException found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.BadResponseCodeException found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.BadResponseException found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.DbxApiException found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.DbxAppInfo found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.DbxAppInfo$1 found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.DbxAppInfo$2 found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.DbxAppInfo$3 found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.DbxAuthFinish found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.DbxAuthFinish$1 found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.DbxAuthFinish$2 found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.DbxAuthFinish$3 found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.DbxAuthInfo found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.DbxAuthInfo$1 found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.DbxAuthInfo$2 found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.DbxDownloader found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
Duplicate class com.dropbox.core.DbxException found in modules dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3) and dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar (dropbox-core-sdk-3.1.3.jar)
```

This is my build.gradle file content:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.home.styles"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.1.3'
}
```

There is only one library file attached under /libs. 
I had version 1.6.x of said SDK previosely in my project and i removed it and replaced it with more recent one if that would play any role in this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56029604/6071729

Comment: Problem is i have only one lib imported and looks like from log file that there are duplicated of the same lib and they are in conflict.

Comment: did you see the answer? i have put all possible situation which lead to duplicated classes.