# Duplicated classes found in modules classes

Tags: java, android

I added a dialogflow library and this error appears.

This error was the same in other projects.

```
Duplicate class org.threeten.bp.Clock found in modules threetenbp-1.3.7-no-tzdb-no-tzdb.jar 
(org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.7) and threetenbp-1.3.7.jar (org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.7)
Duplicate class org.threeten.bp.Clock$FixedClock found in modules threetenbp-1.3.7-no-tzdb-no- 
tzdb.jar (org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.7) and threetenbp-1.3.7.jar (org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.7)
Duplicate class org.threeten.bp.Clock$OffsetClock found in modules threetenbp-1.3.7-no-tzdb-no- 
tzdb.jar (org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.7) and threetenbp-1.3.7.jar (org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.7)
```

the code I tried

```
    configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'org.threeten.bp' //
}

    implementation ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.117.0-alpha') {
    exclude group :"org.threeten.bp"
}

android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Delete

```
//com.jakeewharton.threvenabp:threvenabp:1.1.1'
```

and invalidate caches

[`build.gradle` file on Github](https://github.com/eggham0518/github/blob/master/build.gradle)

Comment: can you post something more clear of your gradle file ?

Comment: sorry It's too  complicated.. I wanted to organize and give it to you, but I didn't know what was wrong, https://github.com/eggham0518/github/edit/master/build.gradle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your exclude configuration you didn't define `group` name and `module` name was wrongly passed.

```
configurations {
    all{
       exclude group :"org.threeten", module: "threetenbp"
    }
}
```

My Complete answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56029604/6071729)

Comment: Thank you! It's working implementation ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:0.67.0-alpha') {
        exclude group :"org.threeten", module: "threetenbp"
    }

Comment: Yeap, but now I cannot use LocalDate from threetenbp.

Comment: @Lasoty, `LocalDate` probably exists in a different class or you have to use an alternative package.