# How do I fix this "Duplicate class error" in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I updated implementation `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.8.0` to implementation `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0` and now I get this error:

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbs found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-18.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzl found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-18.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:18.0.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfh found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-18.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:18.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgn found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-18.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:18.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgo found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-18.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:18.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgp found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-18.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:18.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgq found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-18.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:18.0.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhs found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-18.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhx found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:18.0.3) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-18.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:18.0.2)
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56029393/6071729

Comment: show build.gradle files

Comment: same issue here.

Comment: same issue here, disabling jetified doesn't work.
I suppose someone at google effed up.

Comment: do you have firebase-core in build.gradle? try to set it to 19.0.2

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same issue today, and after many trial and errors, I  finally found that it was caused by a firebase dependency. If you're using firebase in your project, make sure to use the [latest BoM version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#bom) in `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies{
   // implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')  <-- Produces errors
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')  //<-- This works
}
```

If you are **not** using firebase and still get this error, you can try excluding the offending classes directly in `app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
    ...
   }
   buildTypes {
    ...
   }

   configurations {
     all {
       exclude group: "com.google.android.gms", module: "play-services-measurement-impl"
       exclude group: "com.google.android.gms", module: "play-services-measurement"
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I am having the same issue and I fixed it by downgrading `play-services-ads` dependency like this. So you can try.

```
def ads_version = "20.3.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$ads_version"
```

Comment: Worked for me, Nothing worked above "20.3.0" Hence giving +1

Comment: Yes it conflict with with play-services dependency. Maybe they have added play service configuration in this dependency that's why it shows duplicate error i think

Answer (score 1):

The error is being produced due to the conflicts between firebase & google service dependency. So you have 2 options.

You can change the versions and keep doing that until you find the perfect working combination which is time consuming or you can find a solution that works every time so you don't have to play with the versions every time. You just use that solution wherever you get such error.

Here, you need to use the updated method of injecting the firebase dependency as shown in the official documentation.

Put this line in your dependency :

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
```

Then, You can use any firebase dependency without specifying the versions, and it will work flawlessly all the time!

The final code looks like this,

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
```

And it won't produce any duplication related errors with the play-services dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to fix this and prepare your project for later is to migrate completely to AndroidX. First check if your project is ready, `Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX`. Once your project is independent of `jcenter` or any other older library/repo and compatible with `AndroidX` you won't need Jetifier anymore, so either comment it out or remove it. This should possibly fix the problem.

```
...
#android.enableJetifier=false
...
```

In my case this wasn't enough to solve the problem, if you still receive the same error but from a different library, it's possibly because of other existing dependencies, avoid using bundled libraries or wildcard ones *(in which system is left to guess)* make sure you update them all and clean rebuild the project.

If you still have to keep some conflicting library, try excluding individual classes to avoid the error like this from `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
    configurations {
        all { // You should exclude one of them not both of them 
            exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-core-ui"
            exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-compat"
        }
    }
}
```

Official docs on module exclusion - [Excluding transitive dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:excluding-transitive-deps)

I also tried few more things before figuring the solution, like deleting `.gradle` from local machine, incase some old libraries got cached and causing the error, or resetting Android Studio, it just won't work.

Repo I tested the solution [here](https://github.com/mgks/Android-SmartWebView/blob/6834d951a3491b5e0386311f949b4c6668210f41/app/build.gradle#L36), as you can see in this line I had to comment out the bundle module and specify latest updates to individual dependencies.

You can [read more](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#view-dependency-tree) on module dependency errors for reference.

Comment: you any solution ? cos i am also facing the same issue

Comment: @AmirDoreh the above solution only worked for me, give it a try. else, you have to move the project files and add dependencies manually and build within a new app with same configs but new builds.

Answer (score -2):

Add this line `android.enableJetifier=true` to your gradle.properties