# Conflict on class names after code obfuscation on two different SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

When minified is enabled, there is a conflict between the obfuscated names of two different SDKs.

Duplicate class a.a, etc

I am trying to figure out if there is any way to solve this?

```
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class a.a found in modules jetified-amazonpay-hardened-silentpay-sdk-1.3.0-runtime (in.juspay:amazonpay-hardened-silentpay-sdk:1.3.0) and jetified-diagnostics-1.0.20-runtime (com.android:diagnostics:1.0.20)
     Duplicate class b.a found in modules jetified-amazonpay-hardened-silentpay-sdk-1.3.0-runtime (in.juspay:amazonpay-hardened-silentpay-sdk:1.3.0) and jetified-diagnostics-1.0.20-runtime (com.android:diagnostics:1.0.20)
     Duplicate class b.b found in modules jetified-amazonpay-hardened-silentpay-sdk-1.3.0-runtime (in.juspay:amazonpay-hardened-silentpay-sdk:1.3.0) and jetified-diagnostics-1.0.20-runtime (com.android:diagnostics:1.0.20)
     Duplicate class b.c found in modules jetified-amazonpay-hardened-silentpay-sdk-1.3.0-runtime (in.juspay:amazonpay-hardened-silentpay-sdk:1.3.0) and jetified-diagnostics-1.0.20-runtime (com.android:diagnostics:1.0.20)
     Duplicate class c.a found in modules jetified-amazonpay-hardened-silentpay-sdk-1.3.0-runtime (in.juspay:amazonpay-hardened-silentpay-sdk:1.3.0) and jetified-diagnostics-1.0.20-runtime (com.android:diagnostics:1.0.20)
```

Comment: [I think this will solve the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029393/why-im-getting-duplicate-class-when-running-my-android-project) **Happy Coding**

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What causes it is implentation of a dependency into build.gradle module file more than once. But i've witnessed this situation and discovered no duplicate library was implemented until i added this to gradle.properties file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

According to @Farmanbar

> Jetifier tool migrates support-library-dependent libraries to rely on the equivalent AndroidX packages instead. The tool lets you migrate an individual library directly, instead of using the Android gradle plugin bundled with Android Studio.

And for more information take a look at [Exclude transitive dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies)

> As an app grows in scope, it can contain a number of dependencies including direct dependencies and transitive dependencies (libraries which your app's imported libraries depend on). To exclude transitive dependencies that you no longer need, you can use the exclude keyword

If you have problems excluding classes, check this thread: [How do I exclude all instances of a transitive dependency when using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764128/how-do-i-exclude-all-instances-of-a-transitive-dependency-when-using-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Guess only one of these is required:

```
// implementation 'in.juspay:amazonpay-silentpay-sdk:1.2.0'
implementation 'in.juspay:amazonpay-hardened-silentpay-sdk:1.3.0'
```

`android.enableJetifier=false` is rather the default value.