# Want to add both dependencies but it causes duplicate dependency error

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have two dependencies `'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.15.0'` and `'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-vision:0.3.0'` so when I add these in `build.gradle` file. and sync the project. It is showing  -->

```
Duplicate class org.tensorflow.lite.DataType found in modules jetified-tensorflow-lite-1.15.0-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.15.0) 
and jetified-tensorflow-lite-api-2.7.0-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-api:2.7.0)
Duplicate class org.tensorflow.lite.DataType$1 found in modules jetified-tensorflow-lite-1.15.0-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.15.0) 
and jetified-tensorflow-lite-api-2.7.0-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-api:2.7.0)
Duplicate class org.tensorflow.lite.Delegate found in modules jetified-tensorflow-lite-1.15.0-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.15.0) 
and jetified-tensorflow-lite-api-2.7.0-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-api:2.7.0)
Duplicate class org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor found in modules jetified-tensorflow-lite-1.15.0-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.15.0) and jetified-tensorflow-lite-api-2.7.0-runtime (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-api:2.7.0)
```

How to resolve this dependency error. I have tried by adding one one dependencies and now I am getting that error causes by adding this dependency `'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-vision:0.3.0'`

By removing one of these dependencies I'm getting error in my java files.

My **`build.gradle`** file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'de.undercouch.download'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    android {
        ndkVersion '21.1.6528147'
    }
    flavorDimensions "tfliteInference"
    productFlavors {
       // The TFLite inference is built using the TFLite Java interpreter.
       interpreter {
           dimension "tfliteInference"
       }
       // Default: The TFLite inference is built using the TFLite Task library (high-level API).
       taskApi {
           getIsDefault().set(true)
           dimension "tfliteInference"
       }
    }

}

// import DownloadModels task
project.ext.ASSET_DIR = projectDir.toString() + '/src/main/assets'
project.ext.TMP_DIR   = project.buildDir.toString() + '/downloads'

// Download default models; if you wish to use your own models then
// place them in the "assets" directory and comment out this line.
apply from:'download.gradle'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
     implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'
 
         implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta07"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
     implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'

    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.15.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'
     implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.9.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-vision:0.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029393/why-im-getting-duplicate-class-when-running-my-android-project/56029604#56029604

Comment: yes. but not getting which class i have to exclude and which module

Comment: You need to sync the versions of the `org.tensorflow` artifacts you're using