# No static method delimiterOffset in class Lokhttp3/internal/Util

Tags: android, dependencies, okhttp, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am using jitsi library for video connection. It works fine when installed for the first time but it crashes if a user already has application and updates it from play store. Logs from crash says:

> No static method delimiterOffset(Ljava/lang/String;IILjava/lang/String;)I in class Lokhttp3/internal/Util; or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.internal.Util' appears in base.apk!classes3.dex)

There are 2 auto generated files: 1) okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar 2) okhttp3.internal.Util.

From class `JavaNetCookieJar`, this `delimiterOffset(header, pos, limit, ";,")` method is called in `Util` class.

`Util` class has delimiterOffset() method not compatible with the one which is called:

`delimiterOffset(delimiters: String, startIndex: Int = 0, endIndex: Int = length)`

`delimiterOffset(delimiter: Char, startIndex: Int = 0, endIndex: Int = length)`

Above methods are called there in `Util` class.

When I hover over `JavaNetCookieJar` class, it says that it comes from `okhttp3-urlconnection-3.12.1` package and when I hover over `Util` package it says that it's from `okhttp-4.8.0`. I am using

`implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.8.0'`

Fun fact is even when I am deleting okhttp3 implementation in gradle, these 2 files are unaffected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must use the exact same version of all OkHttp dependencies. You can configure this manually or use the BOM to do it automatically.

```
dependencies {
   api(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.8.0"))
   api("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")              // No version!
   api("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor") // No version!
}
```

Comment: its working properly thanks

Comment: This is witchcraft to me. Thank you very much, mister wizard

Answer (score 0):

Check if your gradle has this line:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.okio'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3'
}
```

If so, just remove it or comment it

```
configurations {
    //all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.okio'
    //all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3'
}
```

Now clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: what if i want to exclude this as it may be giving duplicate library error

Comment: @ferox147, this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/68139550/14784590. One more note : I usually face this issue when there are jar files, try to replace the jar files with implementation if it is available.

Answer (score 0):

With an exception like this: [Stack trace of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRDQz.jpg)

I was able to solve it by commenting out the line in `/android/app/build.gradle`:

```
    public void apply(OkHttpClient.Builder builder) {
      // builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
    }
```