# How to create and write to Excel file (.xlsx)?

Tags: java, android, excel

There are libraries for Java developers that have tons of methods which do not work on Android.

I started by working with libraries like OpenCSV, but unfortunately Excel has [known issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953679/how-to-correctly-display-csv-files-within-excel-2013) with opening CSV files.

Then I tried to use:

- Apache POI - It definitely has too many methods.
- JExcelAPI - It works, but only on old binary .xls files.
- docx4j - again too many jars, because it's based on JAXB which is not included in Android.

My question is, how can I create a simple Excel file in .xlsx format on Android, without exceeding 65k methods?

Comment: With all due to respect, I don't think  *"Apache POI requires too much jars"* is a valid argument. The API is extensive for a reason to cover all the excel needs. In programming world, it's usually looked down upon for having too few features, at least much more frequently than having too many. Imho, it still is relatively lightweight. It's the price you have to pay if you want to create an excel related app for android.

Comment: Don't you think that [16k methods](http://www.methodscount.com/?lib=org.apache.poi%3Apoi%3A3.17) only in poi.jar is a little bit too much for an Android?

Comment: Shouldn't the title be something like "lightweight library for ..." ?

Comment: Do you need Excel formulas and styling tools? If the answer is no, go for CSV and Excel will know how to deal with your CSV files.

If you only need to display information in tabular format, CSV would be your best option.

Comment: A `*.xlsx` file is nothing else than a `ZIP` archive containing `XML` files and other files in a directory structure. So all you need is a possibility for reading and rewriting `ZIP` archives and reading and rewriting `XML` files using your `android` pseudo `Java` language. So if all existent libraries do not fit your requirements, then do it using your own low level code. No?

Comment: How is this question not off-topic for asking recomendations book, tool, software library etc... Too bad it has a bounty, and answers.

Comment: Have not tried this - but in .NET you can write to excel - per this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041021/how-to-write-some-data-to-excel-file-xlsx - Maybe with Xamarin it that might work too. I was just taken by your onus on Java libraries, thinking Microsoft has solutions too.

Comment: You should look into http://xcelite.io/ - it builds on top of POI, but the API is much smaller and easier to work with. Simply create a handful of beans and have Xcelite write them to Excel files.

Answer (score 19):

Since this question seems to be rather: "What is the most lightweight way creating Office Open XML files for Excel (`*.xlsx`)?", I will providing an example which does not need any libraries except the default `java.lang`, `java.io` and `java.util.zip`.

A `*.xlsx` file is nothing else than a ZIP archive containing XML files and other files in a directory structure. So all we need is a possibility for creating, reading and writing ZIP archives and creating, reading and writing XML files. For the ZIP part I am using `java.util.zip` and for the XML part I am using string manipulation. This, creating and manipulating XML via string manipulation, is not the most recommended way for manipulating XML but it is the most lightweight way since it does not needs any additional XML libraries.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import java.util.zip.*;

public class CreateXLSXFromScratch {

 //some static parts of the XLSX file:

 static String content_types_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><Types xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types\"><Default ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml\" Extension=\"rels\"/><Default ContentType=\"application/xml\" Extension=\"xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml\" PartName=\"/docProps/app.xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml\" PartName=\"/docProps/core.xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sharedStrings+xml\" PartName=\"/xl/sharedStrings.xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.styles+xml\" PartName=\"/xl/styles.xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml\" PartName=\"/xl/workbook.xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml\" PartName=\"/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml\"/></Types>";

 static String docProps_app_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Properties xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties\"><Application>" + "Created Low level From Scratch" + "</Application></Properties>";

 static String docProps_core_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><cp:coreProperties xmlns:cp=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties\" xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\" xmlns:dcterms=\"http://purl.org/dc/terms/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><dcterms:created xsi:type=\"dcterms:W3CDTF\">" + java.time.Instant.now().truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.SECONDS).toString() + "</dcterms:created><dc:creator>" + "Axel Richter from scratch" + "</dc:creator></cp:coreProperties>";

 static String _rels_rels_xml  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><Relationships xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships\"><Relationship Id=\"rId1\" Target=\"xl/workbook.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument\"/><Relationship Id=\"rId2\" Target=\"docProps/app.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties\"/><Relationship Id=\"rId3\" Target=\"docProps/core.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties\"/></Relationships>";

 static String xl_rels_workbook_xml_rels_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><Relationships xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships\"><Relationship Id=\"rId1\" Target=\"sharedStrings.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/sharedStrings\"/><Relationship Id=\"rId2\" Target=\"styles.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles\"/><Relationship Id=\"rId3\" Target=\"worksheets/sheet1.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet\"/></Relationships>";

 static String xl_sharedstrings_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><sst count=\"0\" uniqueCount=\"0\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\"/>"; 

 static String xl_styles_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><styleSheet xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\"><numFmts count=\"0\"/><fonts count=\"1\"><font><sz val=\"11.0\"/><color indexed=\"8\"/><name val=\"Calibri\"/><family val=\"2\"/><scheme val=\"minor\"/></font></fonts><fills count=\"2\"><fill><patternFill patternType=\"none\"/></fill><fill><patternFill patternType=\"darkGray\"/></fill></fills><borders count=\"1\"><border><left/><right/><top/><bottom/><diagonal/></border></borders><cellStyleXfs count=\"1\"><xf numFmtId=\"0\" fontId=\"0\" fillId=\"0\" borderId=\"0\"/></cellStyleXfs><cellXfs count=\"1\"><xf numFmtId=\"0\" fontId=\"0\" fillId=\"0\" borderId=\"0\" xfId=\"0\"/></cellXfs></styleSheet>";

 static String xl_workbook_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><workbook xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\" xmlns:r=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships\"><workbookPr date1904=\"false\"/><bookViews><workbookView activeTab=\"0\"/></bookViews><sheets><sheet name=\"" + "Sheet1" + "\" r:id=\"rId3\" sheetId=\"1\"/></sheets></workbook>";

 static String xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><worksheet xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\"><dimension ref=\"A1\"/><sheetViews><sheetView workbookViewId=\"0\" tabSelected=\"true\"/></sheetViews><sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight=\"15.0\"/><sheetData/><pageMargins bottom=\"0.75\" footer=\"0.3\" header=\"0.3\" left=\"0.7\" right=\"0.7\" top=\"0.75\"/></worksheet>";

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  // result goes into a ByteArrayOutputStream
  ByteArrayOutputStream resultout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  // needed objects
  ZipEntry zipentry = null;
  byte[] data = null;

  // create ZipOutputStream
  ZipOutputStream zipout = new ZipOutputStream(resultout);

  // create the static parts of the XLSX ZIP file:

  zipentry = new ZipEntry("[Content_Types].xml");
  zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
  data = content_types_xml.getBytes();
  zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
  zipout.closeEntry();

  zipentry = new ZipEntry("docProps/app.xml");
  zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
  data = docProps_app_xml.getBytes();
  zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
  zipout.closeEntry();

  zipentry = new ZipEntry("docProps/core.xml");
  zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
  data = docProps_core_xml.getBytes();
  zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
  zipout.closeEntry();

  zipentry = new ZipEntry("_rels/.rels");
  zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
  data = _rels_rels_xml.getBytes();
  zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
  zipout.closeEntry();

  zipentry = new ZipEntry("xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels");
  zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
  data = xl_rels_workbook_xml_rels_xml.getBytes();
  zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
  zipout.closeEntry();

  zipentry = new ZipEntry("xl/sharedStrings.xml");
  zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
  data = xl_sharedstrings_xml.getBytes();
  zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
  zipout.closeEntry();

  zipentry = new ZipEntry("xl/styles.xml");
  zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
  data = xl_styles_xml.getBytes();
  zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
  zipout.closeEntry();

  zipentry = new ZipEntry("xl/workbook.xml");
  zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
  data = xl_workbook_xml.getBytes();
  zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
  zipout.closeEntry();

  // preparing the sheet data:

  Object[][] sheetData = new Object[][] {
   {"Text", "Value", "Formula"},
   {"Text1", 1.23456, "=SIN(B2)"},
   {"Text2", 2.34567, "=SQRT(B3)"},
   {"Text3", 123.456, "=B4/10"}
  };
  String sheetdata = "<sheetData>";
  int r = 0;
  char c = 'A'; --c;
  for (Object[] rowData : sheetData) {
   sheetdata += "<row r=\"" + ++r + "\">";
   c = 'A'; --c;
   for (Object cellData : rowData) {
    sheetdata += "<c r=\"" + Character.toString(++c) + r + "\"";
    if (cellData instanceof String && ((String)cellData).startsWith("=")) {
     sheetdata += "><f>" + ((String)cellData).replace("=", "") + "</f></c>";
    } else if (cellData instanceof String) {
     sheetdata += " t=\"inlineStr\"><is><t>" + ((String)cellData) + "</t></is></c>";
    } else if (cellData instanceof Double) {
     sheetdata += "><v>" + ((Double)cellData) + "</v></c>";
    }
   }
   sheetdata += "</row>";
  }
  sheetdata += "</sheetData>";

  // get the static sheet xml into a buffer for further processing
  StringBuffer xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer = new StringBuffer(xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml);

  // get position of the <dimension ref=\"A1\"/> in the static xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml
  int dimensionstart = xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer.indexOf("<dimension ref=\"A1\"/>");
  // replace the <dimension ref=\"A1\"/> with the new dimension
  xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer = xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer.replace(
   dimensionstart, 
   dimensionstart + "<dimension ref=\"A1\"/>".length(), 
   "<dimension ref=\"A1:" + Character.toString(c) + r + "\"/>");

  // get position of the <sheetData/> in the static xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml
  int sheetdatastart = xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer.indexOf("<sheetData/>");
  // replace the <sheetData/> with the prepared sheet date string
  xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer = xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer.replace(
   sheetdatastart, 
   sheetdatastart + "<sheetData/>".length(), 
   sheetdata);

  // create the xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
  zipentry = new ZipEntry("xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml");
  zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
  data = xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer.toString().getBytes();
  zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
  zipout.closeEntry();

  zipout.finish();

  // now ByteArrayOutputStream resultout contains the XLSX file data

  // writing this data into a file
  try (java.io.FileOutputStream fileout = new java.io.FileOutputStream("test.xlsx")) {
   resultout.writeTo(fileout);
   resultout.close();
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: I think your answer required the most effort to create it, that's why I will reward you. Furthermore it's really lightweight solution as you said. For now I will use JExcelAPI as mentioned in @GreyBeardedGeek answer.

Comment: It's working but I've to add write permissions in manifest and write to external storage: `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/test.xlsx");` ant then ``try (FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(file)) {``

Comment: just a sidenote: 
This piece of code is limited to excel's with 26 columns, as soon as you try to use 27 it gets corrupted becuase it should go from Z to AA.

Answer (score 16):

First answer: do it server-side.

If that's not possible, just use JExecelAPI - pretty much everything that reads xlsx files reads xls files too.

Every other Excel library is going to be way too big.

Another thought - write csv files, either manually, or with one of the many csv libraries available. Again, most applications that read Excel files read csv files too.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Actually I can't do it in offline app, that's why I decided to use JExcelAPI. Unfortunately because of the mentioned issues with CSV, I won't use it.

Comment: JExcelAPI does not support xlsx writing. Is there a way to do that with JExcelAPI ?

Answer (score 4):

update of Axel Richter's answer:

- add cell dynamically
- unlimited columns (not only 26)

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class CreatePlainXLSX {

    //some static parts of the XLSX file:

    static String content_types_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><Types xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types\"><Default ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml\" Extension=\"rels\"/><Default ContentType=\"application/xml\" Extension=\"xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml\" PartName=\"/docProps/app.xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml\" PartName=\"/docProps/core.xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sharedStrings+xml\" PartName=\"/xl/sharedStrings.xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.styles+xml\" PartName=\"/xl/styles.xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml\" PartName=\"/xl/workbook.xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml\" PartName=\"/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml\"/></Types>";

    static String docProps_app_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Properties xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties\"><Application>" + "Created Low level From Scratch" + "</Application></Properties>";

    static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

    static String docProps_core_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><cp:coreProperties xmlns:cp=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties\" xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\" xmlns:dcterms=\"http://purl.org/dc/terms/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><dcterms:created xsi:type=\"dcterms:W3CDTF\">" + formatter.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) /*java.time.Instant.now().truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.SECONDS).toString()*/ + "</dcterms:created><dc:creator>" + "Axel Richter from scratch" + "</dc:creator></cp:coreProperties>";

    static String _rels_rels_xml  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><Relationships xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships\"><Relationship Id=\"rId1\" Target=\"xl/workbook.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument\"/><Relationship Id=\"rId2\" Target=\"docProps/app.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties\"/><Relationship Id=\"rId3\" Target=\"docProps/core.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties\"/></Relationships>";

    static String xl_rels_workbook_xml_rels_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><Relationships xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships\"><Relationship Id=\"rId1\" Target=\"sharedStrings.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/sharedStrings\"/><Relationship Id=\"rId2\" Target=\"styles.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles\"/><Relationship Id=\"rId3\" Target=\"worksheets/sheet1.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet\"/></Relationships>";

    static String xl_sharedstrings_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><sst count=\"0\" uniqueCount=\"0\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\"/>";

    static String xl_styles_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><styleSheet xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\"><numFmts count=\"0\"/><fonts count=\"1\"><font><sz val=\"11.0\"/><color indexed=\"8\"/><name val=\"Calibri\"/><family val=\"2\"/><scheme val=\"minor\"/></font></fonts><fills count=\"2\"><fill><patternFill patternType=\"none\"/></fill><fill><patternFill patternType=\"darkGray\"/></fill></fills><borders count=\"1\"><border><left/><right/><top/><bottom/><diagonal/></border></borders><cellStyleXfs count=\"1\"><xf numFmtId=\"0\" fontId=\"0\" fillId=\"0\" borderId=\"0\"/></cellStyleXfs><cellXfs count=\"1\"><xf numFmtId=\"0\" fontId=\"0\" fillId=\"0\" borderId=\"0\" xfId=\"0\"/></cellXfs></styleSheet>";

    static String xl_workbook_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><workbook xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\" xmlns:r=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships\"><workbookPr date1904=\"false\"/><bookViews><workbookView activeTab=\"0\"/></bookViews><sheets><sheet name=\"" + "Sheet1" + "\" r:id=\"rId3\" sheetId=\"1\"/></sheets></workbook>";

    static String xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><worksheet xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\"><dimension ref=\"A1\"/><sheetViews><sheetView workbookViewId=\"0\" tabSelected=\"true\"/></sheetViews><sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight=\"15.0\"/><sheetData/><pageMargins bottom=\"0.75\" footer=\"0.3\" header=\"0.3\" left=\"0.7\" right=\"0.7\" top=\"0.75\"/></worksheet>";


    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> sheetDat = new ArrayList<>();

    public CreatePlainXLSX() {
        sheetDat.add(0, new ArrayList<>());
    }

    public void addCell(int rowNum, int cellNum, Object value) {

        if (sheetDat.size() <= rowNum){
            for (int a = sheetDat.size(); a <= rowNum; a++) {
                sheetDat.add(new ArrayList<>());
            }
        }

        if (sheetDat.get(rowNum).size() <= cellNum) {
            for (int a = sheetDat.get(rowNum).size(); a <= cellNum; a++) {
                sheetDat.get(rowNum).add("");
            }
        }
        sheetDat.get(rowNum).set(cellNum, value);
    }

    private static int toNumber(String name) {
        int number = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
            number = number * 26 + (name.charAt(i) - ('A' - 1));
        }
        return number;
    }

    private static String toName(int number) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (number-- > 0) {
            sb.append((char)('A' + (number % 26)));
            number /= 26;
        }
        return sb.reverse().toString();
    }

    private String incrementColumnR(String a){
        return toName(toNumber(a) + 1);
    }

    public void exportToFile(FileOutputStream fileout) throws Exception {

        // result goes into a ByteArrayOutputStream
        ByteArrayOutputStream resultout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // needed objects
        ZipEntry zipentry;
        byte[] data;

        // create ZipOutputStream
        ZipOutputStream zipout = new ZipOutputStream(resultout);

        // create the static parts of the XLSX ZIP file:

        zipentry = new ZipEntry("[Content_Types].xml");
        zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
        data = content_types_xml.getBytes();
        zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
        zipout.closeEntry();

        zipentry = new ZipEntry("docProps/app.xml");
        zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
        data = docProps_app_xml.getBytes();
        zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
        zipout.closeEntry();

        zipentry = new ZipEntry("docProps/core.xml");
        zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
        data = docProps_core_xml.getBytes();
        zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
        zipout.closeEntry();

        zipentry = new ZipEntry("_rels/.rels");
        zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
        data = _rels_rels_xml.getBytes();
        zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
        zipout.closeEntry();

        zipentry = new ZipEntry("xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels");
        zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
        data = xl_rels_workbook_xml_rels_xml.getBytes();
        zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
        zipout.closeEntry();

        zipentry = new ZipEntry("xl/sharedStrings.xml");
        zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
        data = xl_sharedstrings_xml.getBytes();
        zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
        zipout.closeEntry();

        zipentry = new ZipEntry("xl/styles.xml");
        zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
        data = xl_styles_xml.getBytes();
        zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
        zipout.closeEntry();

        zipentry = new ZipEntry("xl/workbook.xml");
        zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
        data = xl_workbook_xml.getBytes();
        zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
        zipout.closeEntry();

        // preparing the sheet data:

        String sheetdata = "<sheetData>";
        int r = 0;
        String c = toName(0);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> sheet = sheetDat;
        for (ArrayList<Object> rowData : sheet) {
            sheetdata += "<row r=\"" + ++r + "\">";
            c = toName(0);
            for (Object cellData : rowData) {
                c = incrementColumnR(c);
                sheetdata += "<c r=\"" + c + r + "\"";
                if (cellData instanceof String && ((String) cellData).startsWith("=")) {
                    sheetdata += "><f>" + ((String) cellData).replace("=", "") + "</f></c>";
                } else if (cellData instanceof String) {
                    sheetdata += " t=\"inlineStr\"><is><t>" + cellData + "</t></is></c>";
                } else if (cellData instanceof Double || cellData instanceof Integer) {
                    sheetdata += "><v>" + cellData + "</v></c>";
                }
            }
            sheetdata += "</row>";
        }
        sheetdata += "</sheetData>";

        // get the static sheet xml into a buffer for further processing
        StringBuffer xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer = new StringBuffer(xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml);

        // get position of the <dimension ref=\"A1\"/> in the static xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml
        int dimensionstart = xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer.indexOf("<dimension ref=\"A1\"/>");
        // replace the <dimension ref=\"A1\"/> with the new dimension
        xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer = xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer.replace(
                dimensionstart,
                dimensionstart + "<dimension ref=\"A1\"/>".length(),
                "<dimension ref=\"A1:" + c + r + "\"/>");

        // get position of the <sheetData/> in the static xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml
        int sheetdatastart = xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer.indexOf("<sheetData/>");
        // replace the <sheetData/> with the prepared sheet date string
        xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer = xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer.replace(
                sheetdatastart,
                sheetdatastart + "<sheetData/>".length(),
                sheetdata);

        // create the xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
        zipentry = new ZipEntry("xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml");
        zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
        data = xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer.toString().getBytes();
        zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
        zipout.closeEntry();

        zipout.finish();

        // now ByteArrayOutputStream resultout contains the XLSX file data

        // writing this data into a file
        if(fileout != null) {
            resultout.writeTo(fileout);
            resultout.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's 2018. Use Microsoft Graph API and create the Excel file in O365.

Microsoft has published a few examples in Angular and C#. It's not Java but it is a good starting point: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/excel-write-to-workbook.

The [MS Graph Java SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java) is Android compatible.

Limitation - there is no easy way to create an Excel file from scratch using the API. You may want to keep a blank workbook and clone it each time.

Comment: I think you deserve some recognition for the idea. I found also [Microsoft Graph SDK for Android](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android), but it has [24k methods](http://www.methodscount.com/?lib=com.microsoft.graph%3Amsgraph-sdk-android%3A1.2.0) ...

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache POI and enable multi dex by simply adding `compile "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1"` to your dependencies in `build.gradle`. You also need to set multiDexEnabled true. That should get rid of the 65k method limitation.

Comment: Do you have any example project ?  That will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to read xlsx file from any sources i recommande you to use CSV excel is perfectly able to convert that type to any of its std output.

Even if you need formula, cell formatting, there are to way to did it use on of the lib you cite or using your own xml parser as said by many people before me, excel format is just a zip with xml inside. Those xml are describe here :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979921(v=office.12).aspx

As you will discover excel is very complexe format and simple retrocompatibility is not their priority . So making your own restricted parser with XPath or JAXB will be an heavy work but not impossible.

But I don't understand why you want restrict number of methods ? if its about making some embedded sofware, in my opinion, you shouldn't use .xlsx, this is a to complicated and heavy file to just save grids ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm expanding on Axel Richter's answer
My code below will add features for you to add columns and values dynamically.

import android.os.Build;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.zip.*;

@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public class ExcelSpreadSheet {

//some static parts of the XLSX file:

String content_types_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><Types xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types\"><Default ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml\" Extension=\"rels\"/><Default ContentType=\"application/xml\" Extension=\"xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml\" PartName=\"/docProps/app.xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml\" PartName=\"/docProps/core.xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sharedStrings+xml\" PartName=\"/xl/sharedStrings.xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.styles+xml\" PartName=\"/xl/styles.xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml\" PartName=\"/xl/workbook.xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml\" PartName=\"/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml\"/></Types>";

String docProps_app_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Properties xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties\"><Application>" + "Created Low level From Scratch" + "</Application></Properties>";

String docProps_core_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><cp:coreProperties xmlns:cp=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties\" xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\" xmlns:dcterms=\"http://purl.org/dc/terms/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><dcterms:created xsi:type=\"dcterms:W3CDTF\">" + java.time.Instant.now().truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.SECONDS).toString() + "</dcterms:created><dc:creator>" + "Axel Richter from scratch" + "</dc:creator></cp:coreProperties>";

String _rels_rels_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><Relationships xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships\"><Relationship Id=\"rId1\" Target=\"xl/workbook.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument\"/><Relationship Id=\"rId2\" Target=\"docProps/app.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties\"/><Relationship Id=\"rId3\" Target=\"docProps/core.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties\"/></Relationships>";

String xl_rels_workbook_xml_rels_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><Relationships xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships\"><Relationship Id=\"rId1\" Target=\"sharedStrings.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/sharedStrings\"/><Relationship Id=\"rId2\" Target=\"styles.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles\"/><Relationship Id=\"rId3\" Target=\"worksheets/sheet1.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet\"/></Relationships>";

String xl_sharedstrings_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><sst count=\"0\" uniqueCount=\"0\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\"/>";

String xl_styles_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><styleSheet xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\"><numFmts count=\"0\"/><fonts count=\"1\"><font><sz val=\"11.0\"/><color indexed=\"8\"/><name val=\"Calibri\"/><family val=\"2\"/><scheme val=\"minor\"/></font></fonts><fills count=\"2\"><fill><patternFill patternType=\"none\"/></fill><fill><patternFill patternType=\"darkGray\"/></fill></fills><borders count=\"1\"><border><left/><right/><top/><bottom/><diagonal/></border></borders><cellStyleXfs count=\"1\"><xf numFmtId=\"0\" fontId=\"0\" fillId=\"0\" borderId=\"0\"/></cellStyleXfs><cellXfs count=\"1\"><xf numFmtId=\"0\" fontId=\"0\" fillId=\"0\" borderId=\"0\" xfId=\"0\"/></cellXfs></styleSheet>";

String xl_workbook_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><workbook xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\" xmlns:r=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships\"><workbookPr date1904=\"false\"/><bookViews><workbookView activeTab=\"0\"/></bookViews><sheets><sheet name=\"" + "Sheet1" + "\" r:id=\"rId3\" sheetId=\"1\"/></sheets></workbook>";

String xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><worksheet xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\"><dimension ref=\"A1\"/><sheetViews><sheetView workbookViewId=\"0\" tabSelected=\"true\"/></sheetViews><sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight=\"15.0\"/><sheetData/><pageMargins bottom=\"0.75\" footer=\"0.3\" header=\"0.3\" left=\"0.7\" right=\"0.7\" top=\"0.75\"/></worksheet>";

ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> sheetDat = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Object> sheetKeys = new ArrayList<>();

ExcelSpreadSheet() {
    sheetDat.add(0, new ArrayList<>());
}

int addFirstColumnKey(String key) {
    if (!sheetKeys.contains(key)) {
        if (sheetKeys.size() > 26) return -1;
        sheetKeys.add(key);
    }
    return sheetKeys.indexOf(key);
}

void addValueToRow(int rowID, String keyName, Object value) {
    addFirstColumnKey("ID");
    int columnEdit = addFirstColumnKey(keyName);
    if (columnEdit == -1) return;//ERROR
    int editingRow = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < sheetDat.size(); i++) {
        if (sheetDat.get(i).get(0).equals(rowID)) {
            editingRow = i;
        }
    }
    if (editingRow == -1) {
        sheetDat.add(new ArrayList<>());
        editingRow = sheetDat.size() - 1;
    }
    if (sheetDat.get(editingRow).size() < sheetKeys.size()) {
        for (int a = 0; a < sheetKeys.size(); a++) {
            sheetDat.get(editingRow).add(0);
        }
    }
    sheetDat.get(editingRow).set(columnEdit, value);
    sheetDat.get(editingRow).set(0, rowID);
}

private class Sort implements Comparator<ArrayList<Object>> {
    int sortColumn;

    Sort(int columnToSortBy) {
        sortColumn = columnToSortBy;
    }

    public int compare(ArrayList<Object> a, ArrayList<Object> b) {
        if (a.size() < sortColumn || a.get(sortColumn) == null) {
            return 0;
        } else if (a.get(sortColumn) instanceof String) {
            return ((String) a.get(sortColumn)).compareTo(((String) b.get(sortColumn)));
        } else if (a.get(sortColumn) instanceof Integer) {
            return ((Integer) a.get(sortColumn)).compareTo(((Integer) b.get(sortColumn)));
        } else if (a.get(sortColumn) instanceof Long) {
            return ((Long) a.get(sortColumn)).compareTo(((Long) b.get(sortColumn)));
        } else if (a.get(sortColumn) instanceof Double) {
            return ((Double) a.get(sortColumn)).compareTo(((Double) b.get(sortColumn)));
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

void exportToFile() throws Exception {

    // result goes into a ByteArrayOutputStream
    ByteArrayOutputStream resultout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // needed objects
    ZipEntry zipentry;
    byte[] data;

    // create ZipOutputStream
    ZipOutputStream zipout = new ZipOutputStream(resultout);

    // create the static parts of the XLSX ZIP file:

    zipentry = new ZipEntry("[Content_Types].xml");
    zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
    data = content_types_xml.getBytes();
    zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
    zipout.closeEntry();

    zipentry = new ZipEntry("docProps/app.xml");
    zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
    data = docProps_app_xml.getBytes();
    zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
    zipout.closeEntry();

    zipentry = new ZipEntry("docProps/core.xml");
    zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
    data = docProps_core_xml.getBytes();
    zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
    zipout.closeEntry();

    zipentry = new ZipEntry("_rels/.rels");
    zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
    data = _rels_rels_xml.getBytes();
    zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
    zipout.closeEntry();

    zipentry = new ZipEntry("xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels");
    zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
    data = xl_rels_workbook_xml_rels_xml.getBytes();
    zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
    zipout.closeEntry();

    zipentry = new ZipEntry("xl/sharedStrings.xml");
    zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
    data = xl_sharedstrings_xml.getBytes();
    zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
    zipout.closeEntry();

    zipentry = new ZipEntry("xl/styles.xml");
    zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
    data = xl_styles_xml.getBytes();
    zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
    zipout.closeEntry();

    zipentry = new ZipEntry("xl/workbook.xml");
    zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
    data = xl_workbook_xml.getBytes();
    zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
    zipout.closeEntry();

    // preparing the sheet data:

    String sheetdata = "<sheetData>";
    int r = 0;
    char c = 'A';
    --c;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> sheet = sheetDat;
    sheet.add(0, sheetKeys);
    for (ArrayList<Object> rowData : sheet) {
        sheetdata += "<row r=\"" + ++r + "\">";
        c = 'A';
        --c;
        for (Object cellData : rowData) {
            sheetdata += "<c r=\"" + Character.toString(++c) + r + "\"";
            if (cellData instanceof String && ((String) cellData).startsWith("=")) {
                sheetdata += "><f>" + ((String) cellData).replace("=", "") + "</f></c>";
            } else if (cellData instanceof String) {
                sheetdata += " t=\"inlineStr\"><is><t>" + cellData + "</t></is></c>";
            } else if (cellData instanceof Double) {
                sheetdata += "><v>" + cellData + "</v></c>";
            }
        }
        sheetdata += "</row>";
    }
    sheetdata += "</sheetData>";

    // get the static sheet xml into a buffer for further processing
    StringBuffer xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer = new StringBuffer(xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml);

    // get position of the <dimension ref=\"A1\"/> in the static xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml
    int dimensionstart = xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer.indexOf("<dimension ref=\"A1\"/>");
    // replace the <dimension ref=\"A1\"/> with the new dimension
    xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer = xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer.replace(
            dimensionstart,
            dimensionstart + "<dimension ref=\"A1\"/>".length(),
            "<dimension ref=\"A1:" + c + r + "\"/>");

    // get position of the <sheetData/> in the static xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml
    int sheetdatastart = xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer.indexOf("<sheetData/>");
    // replace the <sheetData/> with the prepared sheet date string
    xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer = xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer.replace(
            sheetdatastart,
            sheetdatastart + "<sheetData/>".length(),
            sheetdata);

    // create the xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
    zipentry = new ZipEntry("xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml");
    zipout.putNextEntry(zipentry);
    data = xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml_buffer.toString().getBytes();
    zipout.write(data, 0, data.length);
    zipout.closeEntry();

    zipout.finish();

    // now ByteArrayOutputStream resultout contains the XLSX file data

    // writing this data into a file
    try (java.io.FileOutputStream fileout = new java.io.FileOutputStream("working.xlsx")) {
        resultout.writeTo(fileout);
        resultout.close();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you need to add values manually, up to row AZ, change this part of Axel Richter's answer:

FROM

```
String sheetdata = "<sheetData>";
        int r = 0;
        String c = toName(0);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> sheet = sheetDat;
        for (ArrayList<Object> rowData : sheet) {
            sheetdata += "<row r=\"" + ++r + "\">";
            c = toName(0);
            for (Object cellData : rowData) {
                c = incrementColumnR(c);
                sheetdata += "<c r=\"" + c + r + "\"";
                if (cellData instanceof String && ((String) cellData).startsWith("=")) {
                    sheetdata += "><f>" + ((String) cellData).replace("=", "") + "</f></c>";
                } else if (cellData instanceof String) {
                    sheetdata += " t=\"inlineStr\"><is><t>" + cellData + "</t></is></c>";
                } else if (cellData instanceof Double || cellData instanceof Integer) {
                    sheetdata += "><v>" + cellData + "</v></c>";
                }
            }
            sheetdata += "</row>";
        }
        sheetdata += "</sheetData>";
```

TO

```
String sheetdata = "<sheetData>";
    int column = 0;
    int r = 0;
    char c = 'A';
    --c;
    for (Object[] rowData : sheetData) {
        sheetdata += "<row r=\"" + ++r + "\">";
        column = 0;
        c = 'A';
        --c;
        for (Object cellData : rowData) {
            if (column > 25 || ((Character.isLetter(c) && Character.isUpperCase(c)) || c == '@')) {
                if (column > 25) {
                    if (column == 26) {
                        c = 'A';
                        --c;
                    }
                    sheetdata += "<c r=\"" + "A" + Character.toString(++c) + r + "\"";
                } else if ((Character.isLetter(c) && Character.isUpperCase(c)) || c == '@') {
                    sheetdata += "<c r=\"" + Character.toString(++c) + r + "\"";
                }   
                column++;
                if (cellData instanceof String && ((String) cellData).startsWith("=")) {
                    sheetdata += "><f>" + ((String) cellData).replace("=", "") + "</f></c>";
                } else if (cellData instanceof String) {
                    sheetdata += " t=\"inlineStr\"><is><t>" + ((String) cellData) + "</t></is></c>";
                } else if (cellData instanceof Double) {
                    sheetdata += "><v>" + ((Double) cellData) + "</v></c>";
                }
            }
        }
        sheetdata += "</row>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on all answers here, i made Kotlin implementation, which gets 2D array of strings and adds to .xlsx table, which outputs as ByteArray. You can save it via [SAF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77087157/12544067). Also, in this solution, I came up with and added a hack with sheetDataBigStrings that allows you to save a lot more data on devices with small amounts of RAM (it works on Android Go 10 device with 2 GB of RAM, original code doesn't).

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream

private const val ALPHABET_LENGTH = 26
private const val MAX_UNCOMBINED_STRING_LENGTH = 20000000

class ConvertTableToExcelFileUseCase {
    operator fun invoke(sheet: List<List<String>>): ByteArray {
        val result = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val zip = ZipOutputStream(result)
        val xlsxParts = listOf(
            "[Content_Types].xml" to CONTENT_TYPES_XML,
            "docProps/app.xml" to DOC_PROPS_APP_XML,
            "docProps/core.xml" to DOC_PROPS_CORE_XML,
            "_rels/.rels" to RELS_RELS_XML,
            "xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels" to XL_RELS_WORKBOOK_XML_RELS_XML,
            "xl/sharedStrings.xml" to XL_SHARED_STRINGS_XML,
            "xl/styles.xml" to XL_STYLES_XML,
            "xl/workbook.xml" to XL_WORKBOOK_XML,
            "xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml" to excelSheetCreator(sheet),
        )

        xlsxParts.forEach { (name, data) ->
            zip.putNextEntry(ZipEntry(name))
            val dataByteArray = data.toByteArray()
            zip.write(dataByteArray, 0, dataByteArray.size)
            zip.closeEntry()
        }
        zip.finish()
        return result.toByteArray()
    }

    private fun excelSheetCreator(sheet: List<List<String>>): String {
        // preparing the sheet data
        var row = 0
        var column = ""
        val sheetDataStr = let {
            var sheetData = StringBuilder("<sheetData>")
            val sheetDataBigStrings = StringBuilder()
            for (rowData in sheet) {
                sheetData.append("<row r=\"" + ++row + "\">")
                column = toName(0)
                for (cellData in rowData) {
                    column = incrementColumn(column)
                    sheetData.append(
                        "<c r=\"$column$row\"" +
                            if (cellData.startsWith("=")) {
                                "><f>${cellData.replace("=", "")}</f></c>"
                            } else if (cellData.toDoubleOrNull() != null) {
                                "><v>$cellData</v></c>"
                            } else {
                                " t=\"inlineStr\"><is><t>$cellData</t></is></c>"
                            },
                    )
                }
                sheetData.append("</row>")

                // hack to please OutOfMemoryError on Android Go devices,
                // which combines many small strings into a single string
                if (sheetData.length > MAX_UNCOMBINED_STRING_LENGTH) {
                    sheetDataBigStrings.append(sheetData)
                    sheetData = StringBuilder()
                }
            }
            sheetData.append("</sheetData>")
            sheetDataBigStrings.append(sheetData)

            sheetDataBigStrings.toString()
        }

        // get the static sheet xml into a buffer for further processing
        var excelSheetXmlBuffer = StringBuffer(XL_WORKSHEETS_SHEET1_XML)

        // get position of the <dimension ref=\"A1\"/> in the static xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml
        val dimensionStart = excelSheetXmlBuffer.indexOf("<dimension ref=\"A1\"/>")
        // replace the <dimension ref=\"A1\"/> with the new dimension
        excelSheetXmlBuffer = excelSheetXmlBuffer.replace(
            dimensionStart,
            dimensionStart + "<dimension ref=\"A1\"/>".length,
            "<dimension ref=\"A1:$column$row\"/>",
        )

        // get position of the <sheetData/> in the static xl_worksheets_sheet1_xml
        val sheetDataStart = excelSheetXmlBuffer.indexOf("<sheetData/>")
        // replace the <sheetData/> with the prepared sheet date string
        excelSheetXmlBuffer = excelSheetXmlBuffer.replace(
            sheetDataStart,
            sheetDataStart + "<sheetData/>".length,
            sheetDataStr,
        )

        return excelSheetXmlBuffer.toString()
    }

    companion object {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
        private val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")

        private const val CONTENT_TYPES_XML =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><Types xmlns=" +
                "\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types\"><Default " +
                "ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml\" " +
                "Extension=\"rels\"/><Default ContentType=\"application/xml\" Extension=\"xml\"" +
                "/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument." +
                "extended-properties+xml\" PartName=\"/docProps/app.xml\"/><Override ContentType" +
                "=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml\" PartName=" +
                "\"/docProps/core.xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-" +
                "officedocument.spreadsheetml.sharedStrings+xml\" PartName=\"/xl/sharedStrings." +
                "xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument." +
                "spreadsheetml.styles+xml\" PartName=\"/xl/styles.xml\"/><Override ContentType=" +
                "\"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml\" " +
                "PartName=\"/xl/workbook.xml\"/><Override ContentType=\"application/vnd.openxml" +
                "formats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml\" PartName=\"/xl/worksheets/" +
                "sheet1.xml\"/></Types>"
        private const val DOC_PROPS_APP_XML =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Properties xmlns=" +
                "\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties\"" +
                "><Application>Created Low level From Scratch</Application></Properties>"
        private val DOC_PROPS_CORE_XML =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><cp:coreProperties xmlns" +
                ":cp=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties\" " +
                "xmlns:dc=\"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/\" xmlns:dcterms=\"http://purl.org/" +
                "dc/terms/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
                "<dcterms:created xsi:type=\"dcterms:W3CDTF\">" +
                formatter.format(Calendar.getInstance().time) +
                "</dcterms:created><dc:creator>Autogenerated</dc:creator></cp:coreProperties>"
        private const val RELS_RELS_XML =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><Relationships xmlns=" +
                "\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships\"><Relationship " +
                "Id=\"rId1\" Target=\"xl/workbook.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxml" +
                "formats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument\"/><Relationship " +
                "Id=\"rId2\" Target=\"docProps/app.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats" +
                ".org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties\"/><Relationship Id=" +
                "\"rId3\" Target=\"docProps/core.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats" +
                ".org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties\"/></Relationships>"
        private const val XL_RELS_WORKBOOK_XML_RELS_XML =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><Relationships xmlns=" +
                "\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships\"><Relationship " +
                "Id=\"rId1\" Target=\"sharedStrings.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats" +
                ".org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/sharedStrings\"/><Relationship Id=" +
                "\"rId2\" Target=\"styles.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/" +
                "officeDocument/2006/relationships/styles\"/><Relationship Id=\"rId3\" " +
                "Target=\"worksheets/sheet1.xml\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxml" +
                "formats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet\"/></Relationships>"
        private const val XL_SHARED_STRINGS_XML =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><sst count=\"0\" uniqueCount=\"0\" " +
                "xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\"/>"
        private const val XL_STYLES_XML =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><styleSheet xmlns=\"http://schemas." +
                "openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\"><numFmts count=\"0\"/><fonts count=" +
                "\"1\"><font><sz val=\"11.0\"/><color indexed=\"8\"/><name val=\"Calibri\"/><" +
                "family val=\"2\"/><scheme val=\"minor\"/></font></fonts><fills count=\"2\">" +
                "<fill><patternFill patternType=\"none\"/></fill><fill><patternFill patternType=" +
                "\"darkGray\"/></fill></fills><borders count=\"1\"><border><left/><right/><top/>" +
                "<bottom/><diagonal/></border></borders><cellStyleXfs count=\"1\"><xf numFmtId=" +
                "\"0\" fontId=\"0\" fillId=\"0\" borderId=\"0\"/></cellStyleXfs><cellXfs count=" +
                "\"1\"><xf numFmtId=\"0\" fontId=\"0\" fillId=\"0\" borderId=\"0\" xfId=\"0\"/>" +
                "</cellXfs></styleSheet>"
        private const val XL_WORKBOOK_XML =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><workbook xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxml" +
                "formats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\" xmlns:r=\"http://schemas.openxml" +
                "formats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships\"><workbookPr date1904=\"false\"/>" +
                "<bookViews><workbookView activeTab=\"0\"/></bookViews><sheets><sheet name=\"" +
                "Sheet1\" r:id=\"rId3\" sheetId=\"1\"/></sheets></workbook>"
        private const val XL_WORKSHEETS_SHEET1_XML =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><worksheet xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxml" +
                "formats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main\"><dimension ref=\"A1\"/><sheetViews><" +
                "sheetView workbookViewId=\"0\" tabSelected=\"true\"/></sheetViews><sheetFormatPr" +
                " defaultRowHeight=\"15.0\"/><sheetData/><pageMargins bottom=\"0.75\" footer=" +
                "\"0.3\" header=\"0.3\" left=\"0.7\" right=\"0.7\" top=\"0.75\"/></worksheet>"

        private fun toNumber(name: String): Int {
            var number = 0
            for (element in name) {
                number = number * ALPHABET_LENGTH + (element.code - ('A'.code - 1))
            }
            return number
        }

        private fun toName(number: Int): String {
            val sb = StringBuilder()
            var num = number
            while (num-- > 0) {
                sb.append(('A'.code + num % ALPHABET_LENGTH).toChar())
                num /= ALPHABET_LENGTH
            }
            return sb.reverse().toString()
        }

        private fun incrementColumn(index: String): String {
            return toName(toNumber(index) + 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

xlsx is a zip file. So we can extract zip and get xml files inside and then we can parse it ourself to get sheet data.

This should work for both For both xls and xlsx.

Comment: You confused export with import.