# How to save a file to shared Document folder on Android without using the file picker

Tags: android, kotlin, storage

I want to save a csv file in the Document folder on Android (or Download if Document can't allow this). I have the file content in a variable hence that's not the problem.

[Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files) use a new activity :

```
private fun createFile(pickerInitialUri: Uri) {
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
    addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    type = "application/pdf"
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "invoice.pdf")

    // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
    // the system file picker before your app creates the document.
    putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri)
}
startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE)
```

For now I tried the code below but it's in the app specific storage and I can't find it in my document :

```
val file = File(path, filename)
Timber.w("Filename : ${file.absolutePath}")

try {
    val fileOutPutStream = FileOutputStream(file)
    fileOutPutStream.write(content.toByteArray())
    fileOutPutStream.close()
} catch (e: IOException) {...}
```

The log is : /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.mypackage/files/Documents/myfile.csv

How should I proceed?

Comment: User MediaStore for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/64733499/6321878.

Comment: In past, i had a similar scenario due to the short time I used firebase storage as a hack. First uploaded the file to firebase storage and then download with download manager :p

Comment: Thanks I missed this post in my research.

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to let the user pick something first.

You can directly create your file in Download or Document folder.

Or in other public folders.